Why does the computer restart just after a poweroff with WakeOnLan enable?
I run Debian 12 (Mint LMDE) for 10 computers (Dell T1700 with latest BIOS (A28)) in free access.
I want them turn off at 7:30PM to save electricity. And I want them — for maintenance purposes — to turn them on with WakeOnLan option.
But when I enable WOL on BIOS, all computers restart just after a power-off.
I tried a lot of combination with BIOS options. And I tried also OS configuration with ethtool, acpi or GRUB but nothing works.
I tried pm-suspend or pm-hibernate, but it is not the solution I'm looking for. I want a restart, or at least removing all current sessions before stop.

what happens if you disconnect the lan cable? ... how are you powering off?

Some WoL-capable NICs have had both a "Wake on Magic Packet" as well as "Wake for any network activity" mode. I think the latter hasn't made sense in a long long time, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's a feature that never went away. So make sure you're not setting your NIC for "wake for any network activity".

The power on comes after power off even when I remove the cable :-(

I just found something new. When I press the power button, it starts a power-off process and restart just after (same as work the cron to power-off) even without the Ethernet cable. But if I press the button during few seconds the computer seems to power-off then launch for a second the DVD driver before power-off totally. Don't know if it helps.
